# What techniques are useful for solving this sparse symmetric matrix?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-decomposition, sparse-matrices

I have the following matrix to solve.

$$\begin{matrix}
G_1+G_2&-G_2&0&0&0&0\\
-G_2 & G_2+G_3+G_4&-G_4 &0&0&0\\
0&-G_4&G_4+G_5+G_6&-G_6&0&0\\
0&0&-G_6&G_6+G_7+G_8 &-G_8&0\\
0&0&0&-G_8&G_8+G_9+G_{10}&-G_{10}\\
0&0&0&0&-G_{10}&G_{10}+G_{11}\end{matrix}$$

I know I could use Gaussian Elimination or LU Decomposition, but my Numerical Methods professor mentioned that there are more useful techniques in the realm of sparse matrices that could be used, but he didn't specify because he was too busy. I've tried tracking down more information on the topic, but I am getting lost in the a lot of complex articles regarding sparse matrices.

I would like to know some which techniques are more useful than LU decomposition for solving this sparse, symmetric, matrix.

Comment: See [Tridiagonal matrix algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm)

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you. I believe this is what I'm looking for! Could you please post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: By "solving", do you mean the (maybe more adequate term): "inverting" ?

Comment: I have asked Mathematica to compute the inverse of your matrix: the result is awfully complicated. Are you sure all your coefficients are the right ones ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Why would inverting this be good? My linear algebra is very rusty.

Comment: Yes, these are the right ones for this particular problem. I just used this as an example--it's for solving a circuit actually. I will make these type of matrices that I need to solve later.

Comment: As you have not given a **system of equations** (there are no equal signs, etc.), but a **matrix**, I thought you were meaning the inversion of this matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [Tridiagonal matrix algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm),  also known as the Thomas algorithm.